# Show first letter of a list once?

Tags: php

I have a list of directory name and need to get the first letter from each name and just display it once before the start of that lettered group ie;

what I have:

1
2
3
4
5
Aberdeen
Arundel
Aberyswith
Bath
Bristol
Brighton
Cardiff
coventry

what I would like:

**#**
1
2
3
4
5

**A**
Aberdeen
Arundel
Aberyswith

**B**
Bath
Bristol
Brighton

**C**
Cardiff
coventry

```
function htmlDirList($subdirs) {
    global $z_self, $z_img_play, $z_img_lofi, $z_img_more, $z_admin,
        $z_img_down, $z_img_new, $zc;

    $now = time();
    $diff = $zc['new_time']*60*60*24;
    $num = 0;
    $dir_list_len = $zc['dir_list_len'];
    if ($zc['low']) { $dir_list_len -= 2; }
    $html = "";
    $checkbox = ($z_admin || ($zc['playlists'] && $zc['session_pls']));

    /**/
    $row = 0;
    $items = sizeof($subdirs);
    $cat_cols = "2";
    $rows_in_col = ceil($items/$cat_cols);
    if ($rows_in_col < $cat_cols) { $cat_cols = ceil($items/$rows_in_col); }
    $col_width = round(100 / $cat_cols);
    $html = "<table width='600'><tr>";
    $i = 0;
    /**/
    foreach ($subdirs as $subdir => $opts) {

        if ($row == 0) {
            $class = ($cat_cols != ++$i) ? ' class="z_artistcols"' : '';
            $html .= "<td $class valign='top' nowrap='nowrap' width='$col_width%'>";
        }
        /*$currentleter = substr($opts, 0 , 1);
        if($lastletter != $currentleter){
        echo $currentleter;
        $lastletter = $currentleter;
        }*/

        if($alphabet != substr($opts,0,1)) {
        echo strtoupper(substr($opts,0,1)); // add your html formatting too.
        $alphabet = substr($opts,0,1);
        }


        $dir_len = $dir_list_len;
        $dir = false;
        $image = $opts['image'];
        $new_beg = $new_end = "";
        if (substr($subdir, -1) == "/") {
            $dir = true;
            $subdir = substr($subdir, 0, -1);
        }

        $path_raw = getURLencodedPath($subdir);

        $href = "<a href='$path_raw";
        if (!$dir) {
            if ($zc['download'] && $zc['cmp_sel']) { $html .= "$href/.lp&amp;l=8&amp;m=9&amp;c=0'>$z_img_down</a> &nbsp;"; }
            if ($zc['play']) { $html .= "$href&amp;l=8&amp;m=0'>$z_img_play</a> &nbsp;"; }
            if ($zc['low'] && ($zc['resample'] || $opts['lofi'])) { $html .= "$href&amp;l=8&amp;m=0&amp;lf=true'>$z_img_lofi</a> &nbsp;"; }
            if ($checkbox) { $html .= "<input type='checkbox' name='mp3s[]' value='$path_raw/.lp'/> &nbsp;"; }
            $num++;
            if ($zc['new_highlight'] && isset($opts['mtime']) && ($now - $opts['mtime'] < $diff)) {
                $dir_len -= 5;
                if ($z_img_new) {
                    $new_end = $z_img_new;
                } else {
                    $new_beg = $zc['new_beg'];
                    $new_end = $zc['new_end'];
                }
            }
        }
        $title = formatTitle(basename($subdir));
        if (strlen($title) > $dir_len) {
            $ht = " title=\"$title.\"";
            $title = substr($title,0,$dir_len).$opts['mtime']."...";
        } else {
            $ht = "";
        }

        if ($zc['dir_list_year']) {
            $di = getDirInfo($subdir);
            if (!empty($di['year'])) $title .= " (".$di['year'].")";
        }

        $html .= "$href'$ht>$new_beg$title$new_end</a><br />";
        $row = ++$row % $rows_in_col;
        if ($row == 0) { $html .= "</td>"; }
    }

    if ($row != 0) $html .= "</td>";
    $html .= "</tr></table>";
    $arr['num'] = $num;
    $arr['list'] = $html;
    return $arr;
}
```

I need help to get work.

Comment: How is this related to iphone?

Comment: I sense no encapsulation here. ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will display the list of directories, beginning each group with a first letter as beginning of the group (see [codepad for proof](http://codepad.org/Ygw5Xe61)):

(this assumes `$dirs` is array containing the names)

```
$cur_let = null;
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    if ($cur_let !== strtoupper(substr($dir,0,1))){
        $cur_let = strtoupper(substr($dir,0,1));
        echo $cur_let."\n";
    }
    echo $dir . "\n";
}
```

You just need to add some formatting on your own, suited to your needs.

**Edit:**

Version grouping under **#** sign entries that begin with a number, can look like that:

```
$cur_let = null;
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    $first_let = (is_numeric(strtoupper(substr($dir,0,1))) ? '#' : strtoupper(substr($dir,0,1)));
    if ($cur_let !== $first_let){
        $cur_let = $first_let;
        echo $cur_let."\n";
    }
    echo $dir . "\n";
}
```

Please see [codepad as a proof](http://codepad.org/0NXuKa0n).

Comment: Ok this code is working but how do i group all directory name start with number? please check the questions again i edited.

Comment: @James: Please see updated version. It now groups all entries beginning with digit into a group marked as **`#`**.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this, change it to output the HTML the way you want thouugh:

```
sort($subdirs);
$count = count($subdirs);
$lastLetter = '';
foreach($subdirs as $subdir => $opts){
    if(substr($subdir,0,1) !== $lastLetter){
        $lastLetter = substr($subdir,0,1);
        echo '<br /><div style="font-weight: bold;">'.strtoupper($lastLetter).'</div>';
    }
    echo '<div>'.$subdir.'</div>';
}
```

**EDIT**

Just realized $subdir is associative, made the change above:

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<?php

$places = array(

'Aberdeen',
'Arundel',
'Aberyswith',
'Bath',
'Bristol',
'Brighton',
'Cardiff',
'coventry'

);

$first_letter = $places[0][0];
foreach($places as $p)
{
    if(strtolower($p[0])!=$first_letter)
    {
        echo "<b>" . strtoupper($p[0]) . "</b><br/>";
        $first_letter = strtolower($p[0]);
    }
    echo $p . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Prints:

**A**
Aberdeen
Arundel
Aberyswith
**B**
Bath
Bristol
Brighton
**C**
Cardiff
coventry

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to generate a second array that associates the first letter to the array of names that begin with that letter.

```
$dirs; // assumed this contains your array of names
$groupedDirs = array();
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    $firstLetter = strtoupper($dir[0]);
    $groupedDirs[$firstLetter][] = $dir;
}
```

Then, you can iterate on `$groupedDirs` to print out the list.

```
<?php foreach ($groupedDirs as $group => $dirs): ?>
    <?php echo $group; ?>
    <?php foreach ($dirs as $dir): ?>
        <?php echo $dir; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This allows for a clean separation between two separate tasks: figuring out what the groups are and, secondly, displaying the grouped list. By keeping these tasks separate, not only is the code for each one clearer, but you can reuse either part for different circumstances.